# Using Appoptics server monitoring tool which alerts should i set. My site is in magento2

Tags: magento2, php

Using Appoptics server monitoring tool which alerts should i set.
My site is in magento2.
Or a list of alerts to be set for php environment.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is difficult to answer as alerting is very dependent on each person's use case and personal preferences. No two systems have exactly the same metrics and alerts even if they use exactly the same technology stack.

If you have installed the AppOptics Agent, you get [a number of infrastructure metrics](https://docs.appoptics.com/kb/host_infrastructure/host_agent/metrics/) out-of-the-box. It would be useful to have alerts set on CPU utilization, how full your disk is, error rates, etc., in short, anything that indicates that your infrastructure is in trouble.

Given that you can [monitor custom metrics](https://docs.appoptics.com/kb/custom_metrics/) with AppOptics the possibilities are pretty much limitless though. I don't know much about Magento but given that it's an eCommerce system, you could instrument your code to track transactions and alert on the rate of change (the derivative), i.e. when there are large increases or drops.

I think the best approach is to come up with a list of KPIs for your entire stack (infrastructure all the way through to the app) and then figure out how you can track relevant metrics on each, then set up alerts for them.